# Google Drive SDK: Programatically pin a Google Doc revision

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

The Google Drive API v2 Drive.revisions.update method allows the setting of a pinned parameter so that the particular revision is never automatically purged. However as the documentation says, this does not apply for Google Docs. How can we pin a revision so it is never deleted? I have an app that depends on tracking and retreiving certain revisions at a later point in time.

Any suggestions on how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google docs (as well as all native google formats like spreadsheet) does NOT get any revisions deleted automatically, thus there is no need to pin revisions.

If you were referring to .doc, those aren't Google docs.

I couldn't find a reference inside the documentation, but I did find an official reference in their marketing page:
https://apps.google.com/intx/en/products/docs/ says:

`Unlimited revision history
Track changes made to your documents and undo anything you choose. Previous versions are kept indefinitely and they don't count toward your storage.`

Comment: Good to know Zig. Im refering to Google docs (not non-native formats). Is there a reference you can point to which mentions this?

Comment: Grazie. Thanks Zig

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Google is clear about this.

```
pinned - This will only be populated and can only be modified on files with content stored in Drive which are not Google Docs.
```

Try [converting](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/integrate-open#open_and_convert_google_docs_in_your_app) your revision files to pdf (non Google Doc). You can then keep the revisions using pinned = true.